# How connect MS remotedesktop client 10 with Windows 2012 R2 RDS?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-10, rds

So far my clients (Windows 7) connect via Remotedesktop connection (mstsc.exe) to our Windows 2012R2 RDS infrastructure. 
Mac's use the MS Remote Desktop from Mac App Store, which works great too.


Now I wanted to try the MS Remote Desktop client from the Microsoft Store.

It's pretty the same like the Mac one, with one big gamechanger: 
**You can't import .rdp files!**

certificate information is stored inside that files, so just enter the right server names isn't enough.

Is there a trick to import that files or another hack how to get MS remote desktop client to work with 2012 r2 RDS?

Comment: Why not just use the built in RDP client?

Comment: Well I have to, as long as it doesn't work. But why the mac version just works and the windows one is crap?

Answer (score 0):

Well I haven't used it before, but I just installed the app.

If you right click on an RDP file and open with the [Microsoft Remote Desktop](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/microsoft-remote-desktop/9wzdncrfj3ps?rtc=1&activetab=pivot%3aoverviewtab) app the RDP files I have seem to open and connect just fine.  I tried setting the app so that it was the default association, and it seemed to open the saved RDP files I had just fine.

[image]

Comment: I tried it and it only works if I connect directly to that host. Not via a RDS Gateway server.